# mod_rewrite and trailing slashes

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have

```
RewriteRule    ^([A-Za-z0-9-_≈]+)/?$    page.php?text=$1
```

to translate hits like `domain.com/sample_text` into `page.php?text=sample_text`

However, I want the following two conditions to also work (and give the same result).

1) If they go to `domain.com/sample_text/` I want to keep the trailing slash in the adress bar and show `page.php?text=sample_text` (now it goes to the right page but the css and js-paths are messed up).

2) If they go to `domain.com/sample_text/worthlessdata123` I want to strip everything after the /, keeping `domain.com/sample_text/` in the adress bar and show `page.php?text=sample_text`.

I've struggled quite a bit, but I'm lousy at regex and my head isn't working properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rules you have should suffice for the first condition. If someone goes to `domain.com/sample_text/`, the URI `sample_text/` matches and should get served the content at `/page.php?text=sample_text` while the browser's URL address bar remains unchanged.

For the second condition, you need to add a rule to handle that:

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-_≈]+)/.+$ /$1/ [L,R=301]
```

This will redirect: `domain.com/sample_text/worthlessdata123` to `domain.com/sample_text/`, then the first rule should take things from there.

---

Misread what your first issue was. The relative/absolute paths you have in your page content is getting a different base because of the extra slash. When you have something like `<img src="images/blah.gif">`, the relative base is derived from the URL the browser sees (not what is internally re-written by the server). So if the browser sees: `http://domain.com/sample_text`, the URI base is `/`, but when the browser sees `http://domain.com/sample_text/`, the URI base becomes `/sample_text/`, which I'm guessing isn't where somethin glike `images/blah.gif` resides.

You can fix this by including the base in the header of your pages:

```
<base href="/">
```

Answer (score 1):

The first problem you need to solve by using absolute paths for your assets (js, images, etc.)

For the second problem, you need @Jon Lin's solution.